# Spivak Calculus Chapter 3 Problem 10-(d)

Tags: calculus, functions

I am currently working through Michael Spivak's „Calculus“ 3rd edition all by myself and came across this Problem which might not be that important at all, but I am still curious to find out more about it. English is not my first language, so I apologize in advance for my mistakes.

Chapter 3, Problem 10-(d):

> What conditions must the functions $a$ and $b$ satisfy if there is to be a
> function $x$ such that $$a(t)x(t)+b(t)=0$$ for all numbers $t$? How many
> such functions $x$ will there be?

My Answer:

There are three possible cases.

1. If $a(t)=0$ for all $t$, then $b(t)=0$ for all $t$. It follows that there exist infinitely many functions $x$ so that $a(t)x(t)+b(t)=0$ holds.
2. If $a(t)\neq0$ for all $t$. It follows that there is a unique function $x$ such that $x(t)=-\frac{b(t)}{a(t)}$ for all $t$ so that $a(t)x(t)+b(t)=0$ is true. (This includes the case $x(t)=b(t)=0$ for all $t$.)
3. If $a$ is a function that is not always $0$ but has some roots, i.e. $a(t_i)=0$, then $b$ has to be a function that has the same roots, i.e. $b(t_i)=0$. Because of (1.) there exist infinitely many functions $x$ so that $a(t)x(t)+b(t)=0$ holds.

I looked up the correct answer in Spivak's answer book for calculus which reads as follows:

> **(d)** $b(t)$ must $= 0$ whenever $a(t)=0$. If $a(t)\neq0$ for all $t$, then there is a unique such function, namely
> $x(t)=\frac{a(t)}{b(t)}$. If $a(t)=0$ for some $t$, then $x(t)$ can be
> choosen arbitrarily, so there are infinitely many such $x$.

I find this very confusing. Why does $x$ have to be $x(t)=\frac{a(t)}{b(t)}$, if $a(t)\neq0$ for all $t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given solution is wrong and you are right. It should be $$x(t) = -\frac{b(t)}{a(t)}$$